# How to import scss files in angular 8

Tags: css, sass, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am trying to import scss files in angular 8 but nor working.Tried to import scss files only for dashboard module but not working.below given my code.How to resolve this issue.

Getting this error:

Error in src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.css
Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/dev/null'

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kavrfx?file=src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.css

dashboard.component.css:

```
@import "lbd/variables";
@import "lbd/mixins"; 
@import "lbd/typography"; 
@import "lbd/misc";
@import "lbd/sidebar-and-main-panel";
@import "lbd/buttons";
@import "lbd/inputs";

@import "lbd/alerts";
@import "lbd/tables";

@import "lbd/checkbox-radio-switch";
@import "lbd/navbars";
@import "lbd/footers";

@import "lbd/dropdown";
@import "lbd/cards";
@import "lbd/chartist";
@import "lbd/responsive";
```

Comment: Don't you think it should be `@import "lbd/mixins/_buttons.scss";`?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale:Not working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kavrfx?file=src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.css

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psoqvu, Have changed @import path and added css for td at the end at its working. IDK why your code it not working might be some glitch?